# Want to ask about update notice

Tags: joomla-3.x, virtuemart

I've just installed Virtuemart 3 on J3. With VM3, I also installed its plugin for PDF invoices etc. So now I see that updated is available for TcPdf Library. But also there's a warning message:
"Before updating ensure that the update is compatible with your Joomla! installation." I don't know if it is compatible.
Versions-wise. My Joomla is 3.6.0 and my Virtuemart is 3.0.16

Comment: Did this plugin come with VirtueMart of did you install it separately? If separately, have you checked the developer website?

Answer (score 2):

Well... knowing that TCPDF is Open Source PHP class for generating PDF documents ([tcpdf.org](https://tcpdf.org/)), and that is included in thousands of CMS and Web applications, I am quite confident that is compatible with newest Joomla.

It's update 1.0.2 is even listed on [VM project files repository](https://dev.virtuemart.net/projects/tcpdf/files).

I have updated it few weeks ago myself on the same combo J! 3.6.2 + VM 3.0.16 without any problems.